# Return value is undefined (should be string)

Tags: node.js

I just started to develop some stuff with NodeJS and got a very frustrating error.

I have a function to compile .jade to .html

```
function compileJadeFile(jadeFile){
    var pathToFile = "./index.jade";

    fs.exists(pathToFile, function(exists){
        if(exists){
            fs.readFile(pathToFile, function(err, data){
                                    var html = jade.compile(data)();
                                    return html;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine but now I want to serve the compiled html.
So I did something like this:

```
res.write(compileJadeFile("index.jade"));
```

(Don't bother about the unused parameter of `compileJadeFile`, it is used in the original. I just shortened it for this example)

Now if I log the result of `compileJadeFile("index.jade")` to the console it says `"undefined"` :(

I searched google for this but I found nothing that solves the problem.
Can anyone of you help me? I'm used to code in C# or C++ so maybe I'm missing something or something special to Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is synchronous, but the code you are using is asynchronous. The problem is that when you call your `compileJadeFile` function it actually doesn't return anything, hence its return value is by definition `undefined`.

You need to make the function itself asynchronous, too, and introduce a callback and change your method to:

```
function compileJadeFile(jadeFile, callback) {
  var pathToFile = "./index.jade";

  fs.exists(pathToFile, function(exists) {
    if(exists){
      fs.readFile(pathToFile, function(err, data) {
        var html = jade.compile(data)();
        callback(html);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
compileJadeFile("index.jade", function (html) {
  res.write(html);
  res.end();
});
```

Please note that for fully Node.js-compliant callbacks a callback always should have `err` as its first parameter to transfer errors. Hence your code should ideally be:

```
compileJadeFile("index.jade", function (err, html) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  res.write(html);
  res.end();
});
```

Then, of course you need to change the call of the callback to:

```
callback(null, html);
```

Hope this helps :-).

Comment: yes it works fine :) thanks :) now I understand this asynchrony stuff a little bit better^^

Comment: Great :-)! Have a lot of fun with Node.js :-)!